# Почему axios не получает data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, axios

JS файл с запросом:

```
axios.post('file.php', {table: 'users'})
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

PHP на сервере (openserver, apache):

```
echo 'Ответ сервера';
```

Результат консоли:

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: ""
headers: {date: "Wed, 27 Feb 2019 09:54:15 GMT", server: "Apache", connection: "Keep-Alive", keep-alive: "timeout=10, max=97", content-length: "0", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

В чем может быть ошибка? Битый час ломаю голову, что только уже не пробовал. Подскажите куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
axios.post('file.php', {table: 'users'})
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

в php файле сделайте

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: С сервера не приходят данные в data. console.log(response.data) соответственно выводит пустую строку.

Comment: @mccrush глюканул редактор, добавьте в php скрипт echo json_encode($_POST);

Comment: Ответ сервера не изменился. В консоль выводится тоже, что я привел в самом вопросе.

Comment: Собственно проблема оказалась в том, что на сервере, перед возвратом данных, проверял наличие данных в POST, которые были пустыми. Достаточно было оставить echo json_encode($_POST) и убедиться в этом. Благодарю за подсказки.